# how to use mongodb query option in monk nodejs

Tags: monk

I have a `collection` name `projects` and I am trying to retrieve everything except its `url` like this query

```
db.projects.find({name:"arisha"},{url:0}).pretty()
```

This query is working perfectly and returning everything except `url` but my question is how to achieve this in 
`Node module` for `MongoDB` name [monk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/monk).

I am using this code but its not working and returning every field:

```
var projs = db.get('projects');
projs.find({creator : req.session.user._id},{url:0}, function (err,data) {
    console.log(data);                                                    
    if(!err) {                                                            
        res.locals.projs = data;
        console.log(data);                                          
        res.render("projects.ejs",{title: "Projects | Bridge"});          
    }                                                                     
});
```

I did not get where the problem is, please help and thanks in advance :)

**Sample document**:

```
{
    "name" : "arisha",
    "date" : {
        "day" : 18,
        "month" : 4,
        "year" : 2015
    },
    "creator" : "552edb6f8617322203701ad1",
    "url" : "EyjPdYoW",
    "members" : [
        "552edb6f8617322203701ad1"
    ],
    "_id" : ObjectId("5532994ba8ffdca31258bd1a")
}
```

Comment: Sorry, do you mind showing me one of the documents as a whole?

Comment: Just letting you know by the way you are not displaying any of the query in the res.render... in case you didn't realise.

Comment: plz check updtae @LucaSpeedStack and i m using console.log but same

Comment: thanks for the update and I didn't know you were using logs :)

Comment: Are you getting any errors, also are you sure that you have your sessions set up correctly as you might be querying for document with something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To exclude the `url` field in **[monk](https://github.com/Automattic/monk)**, try the following **[syntax](https://github.com/Automattic/monk#monk)**:

```
var db = require('monk')('localhost/mydb');
var projs = db.get('projects');

projs.find({ creator : req.session.user._id }, "-url", function (err, data) {
  // exclude url field
});
```

**EDIT:**

To exclude multiple fields, use the following projection syntax:

```
projs.find({ creator : req.session.user._id }, { fields: { url: 0, creator: 0 } }, function(err, data) {      
   // exclude the fields url and creator
});
```

Alternatively (as you had discovered), you could also do:

```
projs.find({ creator : req.session.user._id }, "-url -creator", function (err, data) {
      // exclude url and creator fields
});
```

Comment: thanks its working :) but hwo to exclude more than one field any idea?

Comment: @maq Edited my answer to include this.

Comment: i just found a trick which is much clear than ur edit ;) projs.find({ creator : req.session.user._id }, "-url -creator", function (err, data) {
  // exclude url field
});

Comment: @maq Nice one. Did you try the above?

Comment: @maq No worries mate :-) Glad to be of help.